# The chance of an event happening is the square of the chance of a second event .

Tags: probability

Question:
The chance of an event happening is the square of the chance of a second event but the odds against the first are the cubes of the odds against the second.The chances of the events are

The answer is given as
p1=p2^{2}

```
\frac{1-p1}{p1}=(\frac{1-p2}{p2})^{3}
```

Substituting p1=p2^2 and
solving we get
p1=1/9
p2=1/3

But p1'=8/9 is not equal to cube of p2'.

8/9 is not equal to 8/27
Where is the mistake?
Thank you.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your computations are correct, if a bit difficult to read, but your checking is flawed because you must remember that $p_1$ and $p_2$ are *probabilities*, not *odds*.  So when we say "the odds against the first event is equal to the cube of the odds against the second event," that literally means $$\frac{1 - p_1}{p_1} = \left( \frac{1 - p_2}{p_2} \right)^3,$$ and the left-hand side of this equation represents the odds against the first event, which from your solution $p_1 = 1/9$ is $$\frac{1 - 1/9}{1/9} = 8,$$ not $8/9$.  Similarly, the odds against the second event is $$\frac{1 - 1/3}{1/3} = 2.$$  And now $8 = 2^3$ and the conditions are verified.

Note that "odds against" will be a number greater than $1$ if the probability in favor is less than $1/2$; and the smaller the probability in favor, the larger the odds against.  This is consistent with our computations above.